# disable options in the List JSF 2

Tags: jsf-2

```
<h:selectManyListbox value="#{bean.selectedColor}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{bean.colors}" var="u"
            itemLabel="#{u.code}" itemValue="#{u.description}" itemDisabled="true"/>
        </h:selectManyListbox>
```

I set itemDisabled to true in f:selectItems but it is still enabled on the screen. Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Answer (score 4):

This generates a HTML `<option disabled="true">` element. The specified behaviour is that the item is unselectable, not that the item is hidden. You seem to be expecting that the item is hidden. This is thus not true. If you don't want to show the item in the list at all, just prepare the `#{bean.colors}` list as such that the item is not present in the list.

#### See also:

- [`<f:selectItems>` tag documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/selectItems.html) - read the `itemDisabled` attribute description
- [`disabled` attribute in W3 HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-disabled) - nothing states that it's hidden

Comment: Thanks Baluc ..when I set disabled to true...the item is not displayed on the screen but I want it to be disabled...Any hint is greatly appreciated

Comment: Huh? You're contradicting yourself in your initial question. Also, the `disabled` attribute does exactly that already. What exactly do you want?

Comment: I am trying to disable an option in the drop down.It is working in Firefox and appears as disabled but in IE the option is not shown