# Showing sublist in a f:selectItems

Tags: jsf, xhtml

I got a list and I'd like to show only a sublist of it. Any advice on how to do it?
As of now the tag is this:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="priority" value="#manageResources.anagResources.priority}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg['error.mandatory.field']}" >
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg['select']}" itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true"/>
   <f:selectItems value="#{priority.ALL_VALUES}" var="status" itemValue="#{status}" itemLabel="#{msg['Priority.'.concat(status)]}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Problem is I got some configuration values in a table. Some of these will be deprecated but there are contracts that still contains them so I used a simple column in the table with boolean values that indicates wether that row is active or not: if it's active it can be selected in the page, otherwise it won't be selectable but still has to be shown on contracts that has been created using them.

For example: if I got a contract with payment method "Cash" and I need to delete this method (so a new user can't use it anymore) I'd simply put to false the flag in the db and then just show a sublist conditioned by this flag in the selectItems because, again, I need the bean to still extract the entire list...

Don't know if I'm being clear :)

Comment: Hi, which part of the 'itemDisabled' in the jsf specs does not work?

Comment: itemDisabled disables the entire value, not just a single entry in it...

Comment: if you use `<f:selectItems ... itemDisabled="true" />` it does, but you can put EL in there and have that evaluated for each item (=entry, = 'value') https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899601/disable-options-in-the-list-jsf-2

Comment: the answer in the question you linked clearly states that you can hide an item in the list only if you prepare the list in the bean. That's not what I was asking :) I need a complete list from the backing bean (cause I need it in a lot of pages) but at the same time I need to hide some items in the list when populating some selectItems' present in the pages :)