# How to conditionally check f:selectItem and disable other in jsf

Tags: jsf

If user enters employess salary grater than 5000 `row.employee.salary > 5000`, i would like to disable Dep3 option and automatically select Dep2.

I tried itemDisabled for render but even if it look disabled, user still can select this option.

Also I couldn't figure out how to automatically check Dep2.

Here is my code:

```
<af:column id="clDepartment" headerText="Department" width="%5" rendered="#{bean.isSection2}" noWrap="false">
  <af:selectOneRadio id="otType" value="#{row.employee.dep}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{bean.depEnum[1]}" itemLabel="Dep2"/>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{bean.depEnum[2]}" itemLabel="Dep3"/>
  </af:selectOneRadio>
</af:column>
```

Comment: add to the `Dep3` item the property `itemDisabled="#{bean.salary > 5000}"` (see [disable options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899601/disable-options-in-the-list-jsf-2))

Comment: Actually i already tried that but even if it disables the item user still can choose that option.